# figure 2 for Crossed Ladders Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-styles, technical-drawing

I'd like to draw triangle like  the following:

[image]

but using the following code which produces:

[image]

The code must represent the structure of the triangle, like that:
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

```
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw   (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
      \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{$l_2=\SI{10}{\meter}$};
      \draw[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.1,sloped,auto]{};
      \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
      \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{$R=\SI{3}{\meter}$}
              coordinate[pos=1](a);
      \coordinate (o) at (0,-0.5);
      \draw[|<->|] (0,-0.5) -- node[below]{$d_1$} (a|-o);
      \draw[|<->|] (0,-1) -- node[below]{$d$} (5,-1);
      \draw[|<->|] (5.5,0) -- node[right]{$R_2$} (5.5,4.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

so i can't manage
any help would be appreciated

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Why can't you just adapt the code provided in the answer to your other question? You've posted code here which seems to be just the same code you posted earlier for your other question. The site is not intended to have people draw figure after figure for you. You need to try to understand the code and draw what you need yourself.

Comment: its not the same code that i post it in other post check it

Comment: The figure here is simpler than the one you already got an answer to. So, start with the code for the more complex diagram and remove the parts which are not necessary in order to create this one.

Comment: There is a lot of good examples in the book tikz-euclid that you can find here: http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/workshops/LatexWorkshop/docs/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf and http://www.altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/Sangaku.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\path` instead of `\draw` for the "ladder" which shouldn't be drawn:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw   (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (5.5,5);
      \draw[name path=A] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (5,4.5)node[pos=0.8,sloped,auto]{$l_2=\SI{10}{\meter}$};
      \path[name path=B] (0,3) -- (5,0)node[pos=0.1,sloped,auto]{};
      \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={a}}];
      \draw[dashed] (a)node[right=1mm]{M} -- (a|-o)node[pos=0.7,auto]{$R=\SI{3}{\meter}$}
              coordinate[pos=1](a);
      \coordinate (o) at (0,-0.5);
      \draw[|<->|] (0,-0.5) -- node[below]{$d_1$} (a|-o);
      \draw[|<->|] (0,-1) -- node[below]{$d$} (5,-1);
      \draw[|<->|] (5.5,0) -- node[right]{$R_2$} (5.5,4.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```